# How to write HQL using LEFT OUTER JOINs on multiple hasMany associations that doesn't expect all JOINs to be non-empty

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, hql

In my Grails application I had defined a domain object called `Order` (mapped to a `work_order` table since `order` is a reserved word in MySQL) which has a one-to-many relationship with another domain object called `OrderProductItem` in a property called `products` and also a one-to-many relationship with another domain object called `OrderServiceItem` in a property called `services`. In turn, `OrderProductItem` holds a `StoreProduct` domain object in a property called `item` and `OrderServiceItem` holds a `StoreSvc` domain object in a property called `item`.

In a query for `Order` LIST, I would like to support keywords search on the `OrderProductItem`'s `item`'s `name` property **or** `OrderServiceItem`'s `item`'s `name` property, in an `Order`, among others. Naturally, in my HQL, I make use of LEFT OUTER JOIN for these like below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o 
FROM Order o 
LEFT OUTER JOIN o.store.managers AS m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN o.products AS p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN o.services AS s 
WHERE o.store = :store 
  AND (o.store IS NULL OR m.id = :userId)  
  AND (TRIM(LOWER(o.identifier)) LIKE LOWER(:keywords) OR 
       TRIM(LOWER(o.description)) LIKE LOWER(:keywords) OR 
       TRIM(LOWER(o.customer.name)) LIKE LOWER(:keywords) OR 
       TRIM(LOWER(o.customer.description)) LIKE LOWER(:keywords) OR 
       TRIM(LOWER(o.customer.phone)) LIKE LOWER(:keywords) OR 
       TRIM(LOWER(p.item.name)) LIKE LOWER(:keywords) OR 
       TRIM(LOWER(p.item.product.name)) LIKE LOWER(:keywords) OR 
       TRIM(LOWER(p.item.product.specifications)) LIKE LOWER(:keywords) OR 
       TRIM(LOWER(p.item.product.brand)) LIKE LOWER(:keywords) OR 
       TRIM(LOWER(s.item.name)) LIKE LOWER(:keywords) OR 
       TRIM(LOWER(s.item.specifications)) LIKE LOWER(:keywords)) 
ORDER BY o.orderTime desc
```

After running this query a few times, I noticed that it only returns `Order` objects which has both `products` AND `services`. In other words, `Order` objects which has ONLY `products` and whose `item`'s `name` property matches the keywords, won't be returned. Or, `Order` objects which has ONLY `services` and whose `item`'s `name` property matches the keywords, won't be returned.

Undoubtedly, I know this must have something to do with the LEFT OUTER JOIN I have for both `products` and `services`. But I had thought LEFT OUTER JOIN means it can return rows for which `products` is NULL or `services` is NULL too. And given that my WHERE clause involving the keywords is entirely made up of OR sub-clauses, I cannot understand why this suddenly turns into an AND condition for having both `products` and `services` be "present" (or non-null) in the `Order` objects that get returned. I even tried adding `p IS NULL` and `s IS NULL` in my OR sub-clauses to no avail.

Can anyone please take a look at my query and see if there's anything I have missed? Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked the generated query?

I think it happens, because you are accessing `p.item` and `s.item` which are loaded with an `inner join`.

Comment: OMG thank you so much! You're absolutely right! This prompted me to add LEFT OUTER JOIN for `p.item` and `s.item` in my HQL to avoid having the INNER JOIN added for me automatically in the generated query. And it solved my problem! Thank you thank you thank you again!

Comment: I'd really like to mark my question as answered by your comment. But I can't seem to do that. Is it because you have to click "Post Your Answer" in order for me to mark it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the generated query? I think it happens, because you are accessing `p.item` and `s.item` which are loaded with an `inner join`.